# /usr/bin/time of a bash script containing ampersands

Tags: linux, bash

lets say we have a bash script containing commands, some of which can have ampersand (`&`) symbols.
I would like to measure the execution time of such a script using the /usr/bin/time, but because of the ampersands the actual work gets done in the background, while the script returns command to the shell, resulting in measurements equal to zero.

Is there a way to suppress the ampersand behaviour (i.e. not letting the commands be run in background)?

The reason why I'm trying to do this is because I want to do a large-scale benchmark (large amount of data sets, and more than several tools (some of which exhibit such behaviour)).

A concrete, very simple example would be as follows.

Create a script `test.sh` containing:

```
#! /bin/sh
sleep 2 &
```

And try running it with:

```
/usr/bin/time ./test.sh
```

The result is:

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 668maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+219minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

The expected result would be around 2 seconds (either cpu or elapsed time).

Please note that the script above is only a toy example. Also, suppose that it cannot be modified (look at it as a black box).

Comment: Well, not using the ampersand?

Comment: I'm benchmarking tools I didn't write :)
This is only a toy example of what I think is going on inside those tools...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of answers from Elliott Frisch and Gilles (in the comments), and is intended to sum things up.

The answer is to create a wrapper script `wrapper.sh` that looks like:

```
#! /bin/sh
. $*; wait
```

The `.` (source command) will force the job to be executed in the same shell and not in the background, and `wait` will wait for all subprocesses to finish.

This can now be run as:

```
/usr/bin/time ./wrapper.sh ./test.sh
```

Please note that using the source command prevents you from changing the interpreter in `test.sh`'s shebang line.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Add a `wait` statement at the end of your script. This will cause that script to "[wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_%28command%29)" for the background tasks to finish.

Comment: The script should be left as is, and should not be modified, the solution has to come from outside-of-the-script.

Comment: @isovic Write a script to call the script you want to time, add a wait at the end of this new script.

Comment: Just tried it like this:
`#! /bin/sh
./test.sh
wait ${!}`

No luck, same result...

Comment: (There are actually newlines between commands, the forum has trimmed them)

Comment: @isovic There is no need to pass arguments to `wait` for your test. The default action is to wait for "all known" background processes to finish (which is the behaviour you want).

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Thanks, I've just tried this (put wait in the wrapper script as above), but still no change... I guess this is due to the background processes being run from the test.sh script and not the wrapper. Of course, when I put `wait` at the end of test.sh everything works fine, but unfortunately that is not allowed in my case...

Comment: @isovic Make that `. ./test.sh; wait`. With the `.`, the background job and the `wait` builtin are executed by the same shell, which is required for this to work.

Comment: That did the trick! The combination of answers from both Elliott Frisch and Gilles works like a charm. A wrapper script that has both a dot and a wait statement (using only wait doesn't work).

Comment: @Gilles: I have a followup question that emerged from this solution. Say that instead of a `./test.sh` script we want to run a Perl script `/test2.pl` (that changes the interpreter), i.e. `#!/usr/bin/perl
print "This is just a test!\n";` then the dot (source) command causes errors as it attempts to execute everything in the same shell... Is there perhaps a way to solve this?

Comment: @isovic If you're running two separate programs, they live in separate processes. A shell script and a Perl script are two different programs. If you use `. ./test2.pl`, you're telling the shell to parse and run the Perl script, which isn't going to work. What problems are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Gilles I would like to have an uniform way to run an executable (regardless whether it is a bash script, perl script, binary file, or anything else), and simply wait until all subprocesses finish executing before returning. I tried to depict that in my original question, but I have to admit that perhaps I chose a poor example...

Comment: @isovic Ok. Your question looked like a shell question (both by its formulation and given the [tag:bash] tag), so it got a shell answer. I recommend asking a new question. You should give more information about why you need that, because there's no straightforward solution, so any solution is likely to require some assumptions.